# Connect to a virtual machine from an external network

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I've been trying most of the day to set up a virtual machine that a friend can remote to from his place. I have a server with Server 2019 DataCenter installed and he can remote to that with no issues. I wanted to make him his own so I made a virtual machine in Hyper-V that is Server 2012 R2. The virtual machine is connected to the internet but I'm unable to figure out how to get him connected.

So far I've opened the firewall on the virtual machine, set port forwarding on my router, turned on remote access on the virtual machine. I've been all over Google with no luck. Everything I find is either for remoting to a virtual machine from your network or just remoting to a machine (non-virtual) from an external network (which I have no issue doing).

I get stuck at login, I put my username & password into RDP but it errors out talking about oracle encryption.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've opened the firewall on the virtual machine, set port forwarding on my router, turned on remote access on the virtual machine. I've been all over Google with no luck. Everything I find is either for remoting to a virtual machine from your network or just remoting to a machine (non-virtual) from an external network (which I have no issue doing).

Comment: I get stuck at login, I put my username & password into RDP but it errors out talking about oracle encryption.

Comment: Please put that in the question using the [Edit] button. Include all important details, including the _exact_ error message. Remember that we can't see your screen.

Comment: So have you ruled out the CredSSP mediation? The fact it’s a VM makes little difference to be honest

Comment: I've never ran into this error, or heard anything like it before. I have no idea what to do to remedy it. Since, to my knowledge, I do not use any encryption associated with Oracle I was at a loss.

Comment: I have finally been successful at logging into the VM from an external network by turning off the "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication."